# Como pegar a cor predominante numa imagem?

Tags: java, android, processamento-de-imagens, cores

Estou tirando uma foto de uma câmera e passando ela para uma `ImagemView` e gostaria de pegar a cor predominante desta imagem, como poderia fazer isto no Android?

---

minha classe proximoLaiout ( escrevi laiout com i por querer kk )

```
package com.example.edras.comeconovo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import  android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;

public class ProximoLaiout extends ActionBarActivity {


    Button btn1;
    int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 0;
    ImageView imgView;
    int colorpublic;
    public Palette.PaletteAsyncListener mListener;

    public Bitmap mBitmap;


    @Override
    // abrindo a camera e armazenando a foto
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_proximo_laiout);
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCores);
        btn1.setCompoundDrawables(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.olho), null, null);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera_intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    // exibir a foto no imageview
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

                    mListener = new PaletteListener();
                    Palette.generateAsync(thumbnail, mListener);

                }
        }
    }




    public  void clickParaIrConfiguracoes(View view) {
        Intent it = new Intent(this, Configuracoes.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_proximo_laiout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

e no caso a PaletteListener

```
package com.example.edras.comeconovo;
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;


public class PaletteListener implements Palette.PaletteAsyncListener{

    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette){
        // Pega duas cores predominantes, uma vibrante e uma "muda"(cor com tom cinza) e
        //separa elas em três categorias: normal, leve e escuro.
        int vibrant = palette.getVibrantColor(0x000000);
        int vibrantLight = palette.getLightVibrantColor(0x000000);
        int vibrantDark = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(0x000000);
        int muted = palette.getMutedColor(0x000000);
        int mutedLight = palette.getLightMutedColor(0x000000);
        int mutedDark = palette.getDarkMutedColor(0x000000);

    }
}
```

Comment: Uma recomendação seria usar a biblioteca Palette, do Google. Com ele dá pra obter essa informação facilmente.

Comment: Eu não vou fornecer uma resposta porque não tenho como testá-la (estou sem o ambiente de desenvolvimento para Android instalado). Mas o princípio é simples: construa um [histograma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histograma) (mais precisamente, um [histograma de cores](http://www.cameraneon.com/tecnicas/histograma/)), e selecione a cor que mais aparece (com maior frequência, ou seja, com o maior "bin").

Comment: Você não precisa fazer um instograma para cada RGB separado. Pode contar diretamente o número de ocorrência de cada valor combinado (R+G+B). Se eu não me engano, o método [`Bitmap::getPixel`](http://goo.gl/JwnPdJ) é o usado pra ter acesso aos valores dos pixels. [Essa pergunta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17740059/2896619) pode ser também de alguma ajuda.

Comment: voces possuem algum exemplo de palette ? não consigo encontrar nenhum funcionando para usar como base ...

Comment: Esse postagem do stackOverFlow pode te ajudar creio eu

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471236/finding-the-dominant-color-of-an-image-in-an-android-drawable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca `Palette` do Android, pois ela permite extrair a cor da imagem de maneira simples ( sem ter que usar histogramas, etc.). Essa biblioteca permite fazer a geração de paletas de cores predominantes em uma imagem de forma assíncrona( fora da UIThread) e de maneira síncrona( dentro da UIThread). Nesse exemplo vou explicar como fazer a geração da pelta de maneira assíncrona, que é mais adequado. Portanto, vamos precisar fazer o seguinte:

1. Gerar a paleta de cores de maneira assíncrona
2. Criar uma classe que seja listener, ou seja, ela vai receber a paleta de cores assim que ela for gerada.

Bem, se você estiver no Android Studio, para usar a biblioteca no seu projeto, adicione a seguinte linha dentro de `dependencies` no seu `build.gradle(app)`.

```
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.0'
```

Agora vamos aos passos.

1. Em alguma classe, utilize o seguinte código para gerar uma paleta de cores predominantes a partir de  uma imagem.

   ```
   // Gera, de maneira assíncrona, uma paleta de cores baseadas 
   // na sua imagem 'myBitmap' e envia o resultado para um listener 'myListener'.
   Palette palette = Palette.generateAsync(myBitmap,myListener);
   ```
2. Crie uma classe listener que  implemente o método `public void onGenerated(Palette palette)` da interface `Palette.PaletteAsyncListener`. Esse método é chamado assim que o listener recebe a paleta gerada.

   ```
     @Override
     public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
         // Acesse o palette gerado e faça o tratamento aqui.
     }
   ```

Um exemplo prático seria:

1. Classe MinhaAcitivity

   ```
    public class MinhaActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

       private Palette.PaletteAsyncListener mListener;
       private Bitmap mBitmap;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.meuLayout);

           mBitmap = // Realiza os métodos para acessar a foto

           mListener = new PaletteListener();
           Palette.generateAsync(mBitmap,mListener);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Classe PaletteListener

   ```
   public class PaletteListener implements Palette.PaletteAsyncListener{

       @Override
       public void onGenerated(Palette palette){

           // Pega duas cores predominantes, uma vibrante e uma "muda"(cor com tom cinza) e 
          //separa elas em três categorias: normal, leve e escuro.
          int vibrant = palette.getVibrantColor(0x000000);
          int vibrantLight = palette.getLightVibrantColor(0x000000);
          int vibrantDark = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(0x000000);
          int muted = palette.getMutedColor(0x000000);
          int mutedLight = palette.getLightMutedColor(0x000000);
          int mutedDark = palette.getDarkMutedColor(0x000000);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: ele acusa que o myListener não existe

Comment: É porque o `myListener` deve ser uma classe que implementa um `Palette.PaletteAsyncListener()` (ex.: `public class MinhaClasse implements Palette.PaletteAsyncListener` ) ou um objeto do tipo `Palette.PaletteAsyncListener`, como mostrado no passo dois da resposta. Nesse caso, a classe ou o objeto criado seria passado como parametro no método `Palette.generateAsync()` do passo 1.

Comment: +1 pela ótima resposta. :)

Comment: Bem legal a explicação, infelizmente não tive tempo de fazer :D só recomendaria o uso da versão mais nova: 22.2.1, que dizem estar até 6x mais rápida. +1

Comment: desculpa minha falta de conhecimento mais, esta dando erro

meu codigo esta assim          
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    mListener = new PaletteListener();
                    mPalette = Palette.generateAsync(thumbnail, mListener);

esta acusando tipo imcompativel

Comment: Desculpe, acho que cometi um erro na resposta, acabei misturando o código de assíncrono com síncrono. Faça o seguinte: no passo 1, remova `private Palette mPalette` e remova o `mPalette = ` e deixe `Palette.generateAsync(mBitmap,mListener);` . Faça um teste e veja se funciona. Se este for o erro, me avise antes de votar na resposta para que eu possa corrigí-la.

Comment: o codigo rodou sem nenhum erro. mas como eu retornaria a cor predominante para uma label?

Comment: Você quer dizer um label de um layout XML ( ex.: <LinearLayout></LinearLayout> ) ou um objeto do tipo View ( ex.:  Text View, Edit Text, etc. )?

Comment: na verdade este traballho seria para reconhecimento de cores eu tiro a foto passo ela para uma imageview e falo a cor predominante da imagem : 
a principio gostaria de passar a cor predominante para uma label na minha activity_menu.xml para que o leitor de tela fala-se a cor predominante. no caso eu passaria para uma textview

Comment: Para mostrar o nome da cor as coisas ficam mais chatas, pois vc teria que criar um conjunto de pares **chave** (nome da cor) , **valor** (valor RGB ou HEX) e para cada cor, pesquisar o nome correpondente. Mas se quiser mostrar apenas o valor da cor, você pode adicionar o seguinte construtor no **PaletteListener** :  `public PaletteListener(TextView textView)`. Assim, quando você for dar **new** no PaletteListener, passe o TextView que você quer como parâmetro, e depois acesse esse TextView no método `onGenerated`.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26669/discussion-between-edras-cremasco-and-regmoraes).

Comment: pronto coloquei o codigo aqui em baixo como resposta da pergunta

Comment: deu certo o codigo mto obrigado, agora so vou precisar descobrir como mudo o valor da cor para hexa ou rgb de preferencia